# How to move Ubuntu from old Disk (upgraded from 18.04 to 20.04) to new Disk (Fresh install 20.04 LTS) -> data + apps?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, software-installation, clone, migration

Got a question, if somebody can help me with a guide or by providing a link how to proceed with such OS move?

I got new SSD disk and want to move my old one (Upgraded ubuntu from 18 to 20.04) to this disk and wanna do it on the fresh install.

I am newby at it so not sure how to do it step by step (heard about `clonezilla` but not sure if its working with version 20.04 lts).

What need to be moved to fresh installed Ubuntu OS /home generally for data but not sure what need to be moved to have rest (mainly apps)? And how after such operation update/setup Grub for dual booting?

Regards

Comment: If the new disk is at least as large as the old disk I would use `dd if=/dev/sdx of=/dev/sdy` to clone the disk. sdx is the drive being cloned and sdy is the target disk. open Disks to confirm the actual disk names. dd does not allow any mistakes.

Comment: UEFI or BIOS install? Will you keep old drive installed? Cannot have duplicate UUIDs/GUIDs if image copied & you keep old drive. You then have to edit UUID everywhere used in one or the other. I still suggest new install & restore from backup. Good way to confirm backup has everything as you still have old drive. You need /home, your data if in separate partition(s), list of installed apps, and if any server apps, their data in /. When a drive totally fails you have to restore from backup, so best to know it works.

Comment: GParted can change a partition's UUID if reformatting the disk is not an option. If GRUB or fstab exist on the disk, the UUID may need to be changed there manually.